# Why does my name appear twice in git commits?

Tags: git, commit, git-rewrite-history

So, I've been changing my email on git commits (to remove my main email from public view and use my secondary instead). I used this:

```
$ git filter-branch --env-filter '
NEW_NAME="New Name Value"
NEW_EMAIL="correct@example.com"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

But now I noticed that on github, for each commit it says "MY NAME" authored and "MY NAME" committed. Which makes me think that maybe I've messed something up. Why does my name appear twice and how do I fix this?

**Edit:** This isn't the same as me asking what the difference between a Committer and Author is. I know the difference. I tried to change both with the above code and want to know what I did wrong.

Comment: @JeffBowman I don't think so. It explains the difference and that I shouldnt change the committer in most cases but I know that doesnt apply here. And then the other answers seem to explain how to set committer on the new commits but not old ones

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If you can show a redacted screenshot of what you saw before and what you saw after in GitHub, that might help. If you still have a reference in your reflog to the unfiltered commits, you can also run `git show --format=fuller <commit-id>` to see if there is anything changed or unexpected in the full output.

Comment: This is likely a GitHub glitch. GitHub appear to keep a separate lookaside database of how many commits are authored and/or committed by each user. When you use filter-branch, you *copy* commits to new-and-improved ones, and then stop using the originals. GitHub will eventually re-compute their lookaside database, but on `git push`, they just *add to it* ... so now it has the double entries instead of its normal simplified single entries.